# Integer solutions of a variable coefficient polynomial

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving, multivariate-polynomial

I have many equations to solve similar to this one:

$$2 a b^3 - a b^2 + a b - 2 a - b^4 + b^3 - 2 b^2 + 2 b = 0$$

Here, b is a base and a is a non-zero digit in a b-adic number, so $1 \leq a \leq b-1$

I am looking for integer solutions to this equation. Short of writing a program to test loads of numbers, what are my options for solving this?

---

My attempts:

Taking the equation $\pmod b$ we get:
$$- 2 a \equiv 0 \pmod b$$
Which implies a = b/2

Taking the equation $\pmod a$ we get:
$$- b^4 +b^3 - 2b^2 + 2b \equiv 0 \pmod a$$
$$ b^3 + 2b \equiv b^4 + 2b^2 \pmod a$$
$$ b^3 + 2b \equiv b(b^3 + 2b) \pmod a$$
$$ 1 \equiv b \pmod a$$
^something seems wrong with that equation

The only solution I know of for this particular equation is:
$(b,a) = (2,1)$

---

Another equation that I have is this one:
$$-b^4 + (2a_2-a_1)b^3 + (2a_1+a_2+3)b^2 - (2a_1+a_2)b + a_1-2-2a_2 = 0$$

For which I computationally determined the solutions:

$(b,a_1,a_2) = (5,3,3)$

$(b,a_1,a_2) = (10,6,7)$

$(b,a_1,a_2) = (15,9,11)$

$(b,a_1,a_2) = (20,12,15)$

Which yielded the linear relation $(b,a_1,a_2) = (b, \frac{3b}{5}, \frac{4b-5}{5})$

Plugging $a_1 = \frac{3b}{5}, a_2 = \frac{4b-5}{5}$ into the equation works.

My motivation for this: The equations I have found link to fixed points in the Kaprekar routine of a base b number.

Thanks in advance for any and all help, Ben

Comment: from 2nd part also could be $b^3+2b \equiv 0 \pmod{a}$, which can be simplified to $$b^2 \equiv -2 \pmod{a}$$

Comment: $b^3+2b = b(b^3+2b)$ is not implying $b=1$, only if $a$ is prime!

Comment: @Stockfish could you please elaborate on that? I am taking Number theory this semester and have apparently forgotten how to do modular arithmetic? Not a great sign!

Comment: More precisely: $b^3+2b \equiv b(b^3+2b) \pmod a$ is implying $b \equiv 1$ only if $b^3+2b$ is invertible mod $a$. For a counterexample, let $a = 3$ (consequently, $b>3$), then we have $b^3+2b \equiv 3b \equiv 0$ (by Fermat), i.e. any $b$ fulfills $b^3+2b \equiv b(b^3+2b) \pmod a$!

Comment: @Ben Crossley: In the second example, do we have $1\le a_1\le b-1$ and $1\le a_2\le b-1$?

Comment: @mathlove yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation

$$2 a b^3 - a b^2 + a b - 2 a - b^4 + b^3 - 2 b^2 + 2 b = 0$$

can be written as

$$(b - 1) (2 a b^2 + a b + 2 a - b^3 - 2 b)=0$$

Since we have $b\ge 2$, dividing the both sides by $b-1\ (\not=0)$ gives

$$2 a b^2 + a b + 2 a - b^3 - 2 b=0$$
Solving for $a$ gives
$$a=\frac{2b-1}{4}+\frac{5b+2}{4(2b^2+b+2)}$$
Multiplying the both sides by $4$ gives
$$4a-2b+1=\frac{5b+2}{2b^2+b+2}$$

Since the RHS has to be a positive integer, we have to have
$$\frac{5b+2}{2b^2+b+2}\ge 1,$$
i.e.
$$0\le b\le 2$$
from which $b=2$ follows.

So, the only solution for the first equation is $$\color{red}{(a,b)=(1,2)}$$

---

The second equation 
$$-b^4 + (2a_2-a_1)b^3 + (2a_1+a_2+3)b^2 - (2a_1+a_2)b + a_1-2-2a_2 = 0$$
can be written as
$$(1-b) (b^3 + b^2 a_1 - 2 b^2 a_2 + b^2 - b a_1 - 3 b a_2 - 2 b + a_1 - 2 a_2 - 2)=0$$

Since we have $b\ge 2$, dividing the both sides by $1-b\ (\not=0)$ gives 
$$b^3 + b^2 a_1 - 2 b^2 a_2 + b^2 - b a_1 - 3 b a_2 - 2 b + a_1 - 2 a_2 - 2=0$$
which can be written as
$$(b^2-b+1)a_1+\{-2(b^2-b+1)-5b\}a_2+\{(b+2)(b^2-b+1)-b-4\}=0$$

So, we have
$$5ba_2\equiv -b-4\pmod{b^2-b+1}$$
Multiplying the both sides by $b-1$ gives
$$5b(b-1)a_2\equiv (b-1)(-b-4)\pmod{b^2-b+1},$$
i.e.
$$5\{(b^2-b+1)-1\}a_2\equiv -(b^2-b+1)-4b+5\pmod{b^2-b+1},$$
i.e.
$$5a_2\equiv 4b-5\pmod{b^2-b+1}$$
So, there has to be an integer $k$ such that
$$5a_2=(b^2-b+1)k+4b-5$$
Using $1\le a_2\le b-1$, we have 
$$5\le (b^2-b+1)k+4b-5\le 5b-5,$$
i.e.
$$\frac{-4b+10}{b^2-b+1}\le k\le \frac{b}{b^2-b+1}$$

Let $f(b),g(b)$ be the left fraction and the right fraction respectively.

Then, we have $f(2)=\frac 23=g(2)$.

Also, we have $-1\lt f(b)\lt 0$ and $0\lt g(b)\lt 1$ for $b\ge 3$.

So, $k=0$ for $b\ge 3$ from which 
$$5a_2=4b-5$$
follows.

It follows that $b=5m$ where $m$ is a positive integer and that $$a_2=4m-1,\qquad a_1=3m$$ and these are sufficient.

Therefore, the only solutions for the second equation are
$$\color{red}{(b,a_1,a_2)=(5m,3m,4m-1)}$$
where $m$ is any positive integer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer in detail.

Comment: Am I right in thinking the method for n variables would be to expand the polynomial, factorise the terms for each $a_i$ as you did on line 4 of the second example then take the equation modular X for X that makes all but 1 a variable disappear?

Comment: @Ben Crossley: The method works for two variables since we can make one variable disappear. If $n\ge 3$, I don't think that the method always works since it is not always possible to make all but one variable disappear.

Comment: There wont ever be any combination terms, so I think it should be doable. Presumably I can just take a product of the polynomials in b and mod the equation using that. I suspect a shortcut will appear if an equation has no solutions. Again, thanks for all your help, you've answered a couple of my problems now!

Comment: can I ask why you decided to multiply both sides by (b-1) before applying the $1 \leq a_2 \leq b-1$ condition?

Comment: @Ben Crossley: We have $5ba_2\equiv -b-4\pmod{b^2-b+1}$ and the coefficient of $a_2$ is $5b$. I wanted to "remove" the $b$ in the coefficient. Since $b^2-b+1=b(b-1)+1$, multiplying $b-1$ does the job as follows : $5b(b-1)a_2\equiv 5(b^2-b)a_2\equiv 5((b^2-b+1)-1)a_2\equiv -5a_2\pmod{b^2-b+1}$ where we could "remove" the $b$.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be the reason. How did you arrive at $(b-1)$?

I managed to replicate the answer by algebraically dividing $b^2 - b + 2$ by $5b$ in an attempt to find the inverse of 5b. Is there an easier way? Did you just eyeball it (by inspection)?

I ask because I have a few hundred of these to solve and I'm yet to figure out how to get Maple to do it for me. So I want to unpick every step of the process so I know for sure I haven't missed any solutions.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Ben Crossley : Note that we are considering in mod $b^2-b+1$. This can be written as $b\color{red}{(b-1)}+1$. This is the reason how I arrived at $b-1$. I'm not sure if you are satisfied with this comment, but this is all I can say.

Comment: @Ben Crossley : So, in general, if we have $kba_2\pmod{pb^2+qb+r}$ where $k$ is a constant, then I would multiply it by $pb+q$ since then we have $kb(pb+q)a_2\equiv k(pb^2+qb+r-r)a_2\equiv -kra_2\pmod{pb^2+qb+r}$ where we could remove the $b$ in the coefficient $kb$ of $a_2$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yep that's very useful. It's more food for thought.

I'll get there eventually with this problem. I've only been at it for 4 months now.

Answer (score 0):

Say $b   \ne 1$. Write $$ a (2b^3 -  b^2 +  b - 2 ) = b^4 - b^3 + 2 b^2 - 2 b $$

so $$2b^3 -  b^2 +  b - 2 \mid  b^4 - b^3 + 2 b^2 - 2 b $$

so $$2b^2+b+2\mid b(b^2+2)$$

If $b$ is odd then $\gcd(b,2b^2+b+2)=1$ so $$2b^2+b+2\mid b^2+2 \implies 2b^2+b+2\leq b^2+2 $$
which is impossible.

So $b$ is even $b=2c$ and now $$4c^2+c+1\mid c(4c^2+2)$$

Since $\gcd(c,4c^2+c+1)=1$ we have $$4c^2+c+1\mid 4c^2+2\implies4c^2+c+1\leq 4c^2+2$$  so $c\leq 1$ and thus $c=1$, $b=2$ and $a=1$.

Comment: Your answer implies that there shouldn't be any solutions, yet b=2 and a=1 is a solution?
How could I apply your method to the second example?
Thanks, Ben

Comment: I made an edit @BenCrossley